# Stop plotting on MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a question about stopping a plot on matlab. I use given code to plot my trajectory. 
But the case here is that, I have a drop-down menu and I'm trying to control my plot speed using drop-down( pop-up) menu.

Pop-up menu works as given below:

```
    function animation_speed_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    % hObject    handle to threeDOF_animation_speed (see GCBO)
    % eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
    % handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
    global plot_step
    switch get(handles.animation_speed,'Value')  
        case 1       

            run('create_animation.m')
        case 2

            run('create_animation.m')
end
```

and here is the create_animation.m file :

```
         if get(handles.animation_speed,'Value')==1
             plot_step=5;
         elseif get(handles.animation_speed,'Value')==2
             plot_step=10;
    end


    for i = 1:plot_step:length(x)

     addpoints(trajectory,y(i),x(i))
      drawnow
      hold on   
end
```

The problem is when I select option '1' (plot_step=5) and then change it as '2' (plot_step=10) without waiting the finishing of the loop, it works like that:
It starts to plot my points with case 1 and then it turns to case 2. ( Everything is normal untill now.) 
However, it continue to plot case 1. I do not want to see case 1 again. 
How can I fix this?

(PS: I attached a gif file I select 2x at the beginning and then I select 8x. After it finish to plot 8x it starts to continue 2x again.)

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Inside your loop you need to check if a new animation has started, and if so quit the loop. — What is happening here is that the 2x animation is running, the GUI callback interrupts it to run the 8x animation, and when that finishes, the code that was interrupted can continue working. So you need to stop that code explicitly.

Comment: First, thank you for your comment! Do you have any suggestion to how can I check a new animation has started?